# Access violation when loading application

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, access-violation

I have an application that is having issues loading. I'm getting this error using Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 X86 on Windows 7 x86:

```
msvcrt!memcpy+0x15c:
```

The application works fine on a new install of windows and also doesn't work if I uninstall all the updates leading up to the issue. I even went as far as uninstalling Microsoft Office 2010 and its updates to be sure.

I know the application relies on Visual C++, I am also not the developer and don't have any symbols or source code. I was wondering if you could look at the stacktrace and let me know what you think. I have ran process monitor on a working and non-working machine and the only difference is it gets information about C: then loads a logon.ini (logon screen) on the working machine, but on the non-working machine, it doesn't get to the logon screen and just crashes. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Stack Trace:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TcNav.exe
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00400000 004e8000   TcNav.exe
ModLoad: 77bc0000 77d01000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 77980000 77a54000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 75da0000 75deb000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 26800000 2680f000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\lcd_client.dll
ModLoad: 17000000 170f9000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\PnwLib.dll
ModLoad: 72a70000 72a77000   C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
ModLoad: 76650000 76685000   C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 76020000 760cc000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 76320000 763c2000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 768f0000 768f6000   C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
ModLoad: 19000000 19007000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\strdatacvt.dll
ModLoad: 6a670000 6a78c000   C:\Windows\system32\MFC42.DLL
ModLoad: 761f0000 762b9000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77d10000 77d5e000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 76a80000 76a8a000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 763d0000 7646d000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 77a60000 77bbc000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 760d0000 7615f000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 72780000 7280c000   C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
ModLoad: 77d60000 77e01000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 76a90000 76aa9000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 18500000 18506000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\ResMgr.dll
ModLoad: 69260000 69272000   C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
ModLoad: 40800000 40806000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\VersionDLL.dll
ModLoad: 50800000 50815000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\ExceptionDump.dll
ModLoad: 76610000 7663b000   C:\Windows\system32\IMAGEHLP.dll
ModLoad: 75110000 75121000   C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 75660000 75669000   C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
ModLoad: 75990000 759a9000   C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
ModLoad: 751f0000 751ff000   C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
ModLoad: 6a420000 6a471000   C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
ModLoad: 68240000 68251000   C:\Windows\system32\MSVCIRT.dll
ModLoad: 17500000 17538000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\pnwrpc.dll
ModLoad: 27000000 27017000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\NTSecurity.dll
ModLoad: 60000000 6001d000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\AcqClientDlg.dll
ModLoad: 21000000 21082000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCDLG.dll
ModLoad: 61100000 6111b000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\cam_client.dll
ModLoad: 20000000 200c7000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\sysconf.dll
ModLoad: 20500000 2060a000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\tcdata.dll
ModLoad: 23000000 23006000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCMSG.dll
ModLoad: 25500000 2551c000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCUTIL.dll
ModLoad: 24800000 24854000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCSECURITY.dll
ModLoad: 50000000 50006000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\ML.dll
ModLoad: 21500000 216bc000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TcFile.dll
ModLoad: 64100000 64116000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\mcs_client.dll
ModLoad: 12800000 12815000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\aqm_client.dll
ModLoad: 22000000 2201a000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCFILEUI.dll
ModLoad: 77900000 7797b000   C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
ModLoad: 769d0000 76a27000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 72d20000 72da4000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_ec86b8d6858ec0bc\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 76ab0000 776fb000   C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 61000000 61033000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\AcqClientInt.dll
ModLoad: 26000000 2600c000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\acq_rpc_client.dll
ModLoad: 66100000 66138000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\SetupHelper.dll
(1eb8.a94): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0012fb08 edx=77c071b4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77c609c6 esp=0012fb24 ebp=0012fb50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
77c609c6 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 76690000 766af000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 76900000 769cc000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 72720000 72758000   C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
ModLoad: 75510000 75532000   C:\Windows\system32\LOGONCLI.DLL
ModLoad: 76640000 76645000   C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 64bc0000 64bc8000   C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
ModLoad: 75270000 75299000   C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
ModLoad: 64ba0000 64bb4000   C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
ModLoad: 64b80000 64b97000   C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
ModLoad: 64b70000 64b78000   C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
ModLoad: 69570000 6957b000   C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
(1eb8.a94): Unknown exception - code 000006ba (first chance)
ModLoad: 75a20000 75a3b000   C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 75ab0000 75abc000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 74800000 74840000   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 16500000 16850000   C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\PnwGResENU.DLL
ModLoad: 743d0000 743e3000   C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
ModLoad: 74ef0000 74f11000   C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 76a30000 76a75000   C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
ModLoad: 697d0000 697db000   C:\Windows\System32\perfproc.dll
ModLoad: 697d0000 697db000   C:\Windows\System32\perfproc.dll
ModLoad: 75b20000 75b2e000   C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
ModLoad: 754d0000 7550c000   C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 74e60000 74e65000   C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
ModLoad: 75750000 75756000   C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
ModLoad: 75a00000 75a08000   C:\Windows\system32\secur32.dll
ModLoad: 75590000 755a7000   C:\Windows\system32\cryptsp.dll
ModLoad: 75430000 75438000   C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
ModLoad: 690a0000 69103000   C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcApi.dll
ModLoad: 69090000 69099000   C:\Program Files\McAfee\Host Intrusion Prevention\HcThe.dll
ModLoad: 75480000 754c4000   C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 75030000 7504c000   C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 75020000 75027000   C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
ModLoad: 73330000 73336000   C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
ModLoad: 736e0000 73718000   C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
ModLoad: 75540000 75582000   C:\Windows\system32\msv1_0.DLL
ModLoad: 757c0000 757d1000   C:\Windows\system32\cryptdll.dll
(1eb8.a94): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
ModLoad: 74950000 74aee000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\comctl32.DLL
(1eb8.a94): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCSECURITY.dll
eax=000504c2 ebx=000504ca ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=0012eb1c edi=00000004
eip=7602996a esp=0012eaa4 ebp=0012eaac iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010297
msvcrt!memcpy+0x15c:
7602996a 89448ffc        mov     dword ptr [edi+ecx*4-4],eax ds:0023:00000004=????????
0:000> g
(1eb8.a94): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=000504c2 ebx=000504ca ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=0012eb1c edi=00000004
eip=7602996a esp=0012eaa4 ebp=0012eaac iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010297
msvcrt!memcpy+0x15c:
7602996a 89448ffc        mov     dword ptr [edi+ecx*4-4],eax ds:0023:00000004=????????
0:000> ~*
.  0  Id: 1eb8.a94 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
      Start: *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for TcNav.exe
TcNav!WinMainCRTStartup (0045f162)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
   1  Id: 1eb8.c08 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffde000 Unfrozen
      Start: ntdll!TppWorkerThread (77bf03cf)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
   2  Id: 1eb8.1148 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdd000 Unfrozen
      Start: ntdll!TppWaiterpThread (77befcf7)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
   3  Id: 1eb8.d1c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdb000 Unfrozen
      Start: *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\pnwrpc.dll
pnwrpc!start_thread_main (17517790)
      Priority: 1  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
   4  Id: 1eb8.1a1c Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffdc000 Unfrozen
      Start: ntdll!TppWorkerThread (77bf03cf)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
   5  Id: 1eb8.1c88 Suspend: 1 Teb: 7ffda000 Unfrozen
      Start: ntdll!TppWorkerThread (77bf03cf)
      Priority: 0  Priority class: 32  Affinity: 3
0:000> ~0s
eax=000504c2 ebx=000504ca ecx=00000001 edx=00000000 esi=0012eb1c edi=00000004
eip=7602996a esp=0012eaa4 ebp=0012eaac iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010297
msvcrt!memcpy+0x15c:
7602996a 89448ffc        mov     dword ptr [edi+ecx*4-4],eax ds:0023:00000004=????????
0:000> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0012eaac 24821b66 msvcrt!memcpy+0x15c
01 0012eb14 248259a0 TCSECURITY!SharedMemory::Dialog+0x46
02 0012eb70 248052cb TCSECURITY!CTcUAF::LockDialog+0x30
03 0012ebe4 6a6c1123 TCSECURITY!CLogonDlg::OnInitDialog+0x8b
04 0012ebec 7620c4e7 MFC42!AfxDlgProc+0x35
05 0012ec18 76225855 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
06 0012ec94 762259f3 USER32!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow+0xd6
07 0012ecdc 76217206 USER32!DefDlgProcWorker+0xa8
08 0012ecf8 7620c4e7 USER32!DefDlgProcA+0x22
09 0012ed24 7620c5e7 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0a 0012ed9c 76201b31 USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x14b
0b 0012edcc 76222bee USER32!CallWindowProcAorW+0x99
0c 0012edec 6a683319 USER32!CallWindowProcA+0x1b
0d 0012ee0c 6a68336a MFC42!CWnd::DefWindowProcA+0x51
0e 0012ee20 6a6c1bff MFC42!CWnd::Default+0x27
0f 0012ee2c 6a68385d MFC42!CDialog::HandleInitDialog+0x60
10 0012eeb4 6a683687 MFC42!CWnd::OnWndMsg+0x62f
11 0012eedc 6a68a361 MFC42!CWnd::WindowProc+0x2e
12 0012ef44 6a68a2b9 MFC42!AfxCallWndProc+0xb5
13 0012ef68 6a68a571 MFC42!AfxWndProc+0x3e
14 0012ef9c 7620c4e7 MFC42!AfxWndProcBase+0x57
15 0012efc8 7620c5e7 USER32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
16 0012f040 76205294 USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x14b
17 0012f080 76224f6c USER32!SendMessageWorker+0x4d0
18 0012f13c 7622535a USER32!InternalCreateDialog+0xb0d
19 0012f160 76217238 USER32!CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW+0x33
1a 0012f180 6a6c18b9 USER32!CreateDialogIndirectParamA+0x1b
1b 0012f1ec 6a6c1aa0 MFC42!CWnd::CreateDlgIndirect+0x19c
1c 0012f238 24825b8a MFC42!CDialog::DoModal+0xf4
1d 0012f3a8 248220dc TCSECURITY!CTcUAF::DoWorkstationLogon+0x1ca
1e 0012f480 2481f446 TCSECURITY!CTcUAF::CTcUAF+0x24c
1f 0012f5cc 2481ec38 TCSECURITY!CTcSecurityApp::Logon+0x116
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\TCDLG.dll
20 0012f8fc 2101aa59 TCSECURITY!CTcSecurityApp::InitInstance+0xc08
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\PenExe\TcCS\Ver6.3.2\Bin\AcqClientDlg.dll
21 0012faa8 60001405 TCDLG!CPnwWinApp::InitInstance+0x89
22 0012fb04 0043a06c AcqClientDlg!CPnwAcqClientApp::InitInstance+0x15
23 0012fec4 6a693519 TcNav!pnw_TcNavApp::InitInstance+0xac
24 0012fed8 0045fedf MFC42!AfxWinMain+0x4f
25 0012ff88 779cee6c TcNav!WinMain+0x15
26 0012ff94 77c23ab3 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
27 0012ffd4 77c23a86 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
28 0012ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Comment: Please post the code. What you did to try and fix the problem does not make sense.

Comment: we can't help you without code.

Comment: What code do you want? I don't have the source code. The program is called TotalChrom by Perkin Elmer. Version 6.3.2

Also, on the non working machine, the process crashes at Operation : CloseFile - Path C:\Windows\WindowsShell.Manifest with Result of Success. Then after that it starts C:\windows\system32\WerFault.exe

On a working machine it does the CloseFile WindowsShell.Manifest, but after it does CreateFile - Path - C:\ with Result Success

Comment: Screen Shots: http://imgur.com/a/TkiFX

The reason I uninstalled updates because I believe this stopped working when Visual C++ 2010 Redistribute got installed

Comment: This was defiantly caused by a Windows update, I installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 x86 and installed a batch of updates and after a reboot, it now does the same thing as the non-working machines do. I believe it was either KB974945, KB2251489, KB2251491, KB2251487. I am currently narrowing down to the single KB. Hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: Well after installing the same updates as before, I noticed it still didn't crash. I also noticed McAfee HIPS and DLP Endpoint haven't been installed yet. Trying that next to see if that causes the crash

Answer (score 1):

McAfee H.I.P.S was the culprit.  After I uninstalled and rebooted it worked.